# Computing Fourier Coeffs of an $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am an undergrad studying Fourier series in the context of Riemann integrable functions.

I am wondering if $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ then does the Fourier series of $f$ converge to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm?

What I am having trouble with is, if $f$ is merely $L^2$, it may not be integrable, so how can I even compute the Fourier coefficients?

I know that the Fourier series is $ L^2$ convergent for Riemann integrable functions.

If the function is merely $ L^2$, do I know whether or not the function is Lesbesgue integrable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, then 
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\mathrm dx=\langle f,e^{inx}\rangle
$$
is well defined, it's the inner product of two functions in $L^2$! And yes the Fourier series converge to $f$ in $L^2$, as they are a complete system of functions.

Also, note that while this isn't necessary for your question, you do have integrability by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|\langle f,1\rangle|= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f|\cdot 1\leq \sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f|^2}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}
$$
and we have that $f\in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$.